# Strange text output of e.getSource() on MouseEvent e

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I want to be able to print MouseEvent e, I have seen people using the getSource() method to do this, however mine doesn't give the exact output I want. In other code people print e.getSource() and it gives the direct path to the image.

When I print e.getSource():

```
javax.swing.JLabel[,224,7,23x20,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=file:/C:/Users/Sam/workspace/RS%20Calculator/bin/Hitpoints_icon.png,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=C ENTER,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

This output includes the image path that I want to access - but also lots of other random information.

How can I get to print only the image path? (`/C:/Users/Sam/workspace/RS%20Calculator/bin/Hitpoints_icon.png`)

```
    for(JLabel j : jLabelArray){
        j = new JLabel(imageIcons[n]);

        j.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                setSize(650,400);
                System.out.println(e.getSource());
                iconClicked(e);
            }

        });

        add(j);
        n++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The source returned by Java is correct since the MouseListener was added to the JLabel and not to an image. If you want the ImageIcon that the label contains, then simply extract it. Note that you're usually better off using the mousePressed method rather than mouseClicked.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
   ImageIcon icon = label.getIcon();
   // ....
}
```

As a side rec, this troubles me:

```
setSize(650,400);
```

You should usually avoid trying to set sizes of things. Mind if I ask, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I remember seeing your name when I was trying to find an answer for this =p, I basically load in a bunch of images into a screen. And when some1 clicks on one, the screen size gets bigger. I'm trying to print the mouse event e, and then compare it with the images on screen to find which image was clicked, and then do stuff based on that. Thanks alot for the fast + clear answer